# What about the continuity of these functions in the uniform topology?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $f, g, h \colon \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^\omega$ be defined by
$$
\begin{align}
f(t) &:= \big(t,2t,3t,\ldots \big),\\ 
g(t) &:= \big(t,t,t,\ldots\big),\\ 
h(t) &:= \left( t,\frac{t}{2},\frac{t}{3},\ldots\right)
\end{align}
$$
for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. How to determine whether these functions are continuous relative to the uniform topology on $\mathbb{R}^\omega$? We of course assume that $\mathbb{R}$ is given the usual topology.

Answer (score 6):

HINTS:

1. Let $U=\{x\in\Bbb R^\omega:\|x\|<1\}$, where $\|x\|=\sup_{n\in\omega}|x_n|$. $U$ is open in $\Bbb R^\omega$. (Why?) What is $f^{-1}[U]$? Is it open in $\Bbb R$?
2. Show that for any $s,t\in\Bbb R$, $\|g(s)-g(t)\|=|s-t|$; use this to show that $g$ is continuous. In fact you can use it to show that $g$ is even a homeomorphism.
3. Show that for any $s,t\in\Bbb R$, $\|h(s)-h(t)\|=|s-t|$.

Comment: please note that here we're using the uniform metric on $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ which is defined as follows: $$\tilde{\rho}(x,y) \colon= \sup\{ \min(\vert x_n - y_n \vert, 1) : n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots\} \forall x \colon= (x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}, y= (x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in \mathbb{R}^\omega$$. So do you think you should revise your answer?

Comment: @Saaqib: It’s the same thing, just a different notation: $\|x-y\|$, as I defined it, is exactly the same as your $\tilde{\rho}(x,y)$.