# Continuous functions in topology

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to solve the following problem:
In which topologies (uniform, product, box) are the following functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R^\omega}$ continuous?

$f(t)=(t,2t,3t,....)$

$g(t)=(t,t,t,.......)$

$h(t)= (t,\frac{1}{2}t, \frac{1}{3}t,...)$

I dont get why do the function have only one variable? and what is their meaning? Can we somehow draw them like calculus functions? It is not very intuitive. To prove continuity I think we have to prove that inverse images of these functions maps open sets to open sets in $\mathbb{R}$. How can we think of open sets here?

Comment: The answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/297303/12042) has some fairly generous hints for the uniform topology.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I am not quite looking for answers right now. This is because I dont know what the question means exactly. I am just trying to figure out how to go about thinking for such a problem

Comment: $\Bbb R^\omega$ is the set of infinite sequences of real numbers; $f,g$, and $h$ are functions from $\Bbb R$ to this set of sequences. The function $f$, for instance, sends the real number $\pi$ to the sequence $\langle \pi,2\pi,3\pi,\ldots\rangle$. Three important topologies on this set of sequences are the uniform topology, the product topology, and the box topology. Each of them makes $\Bbb R^\omega$ a topological space, and we can ask whether $f,g$, or $h$ is continuous when we give $\Bbb R^\omega$ one of these topologies and the domain $\Bbb R$ its usual topology. In order to answer ...

Comment: ... the question, one must understand the three topologies. You should at this point have been told what a base for each of them is. Can you say what a basic open nbhd of some sequence $\langle x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots\rangle$ is in the uniform topology? That one’s probably the easiest. The box topology? The ordinary product topology?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: To show that open sets map to open set how can you show that the open set in the sequence maps to open set in the number (which does not make a lot of sense here) but which is what we need to see if a function is continuous

Comment: You don’t want to show that open sets map to open sets: you want to show that the inverse images of open sets are open. (I think from the later part of the sentence that you may have realized that, but it’s not what you actually said.) What you have to show is that if $U$ is an open set in $\Bbb R^\omega$ (in whichever one of the three topologies you’re considering), then the set of real numbers that get mapped into $U$ (by the function that you’re considering) is open in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: To say this in terms of a specific example, suppose that you’re trying to show that $f$ is continuous when $\Bbb R^\omega$ has the box topology. Then you have to show that for any $x\in\Bbb R$ and any basic open nbhd $U$ of $f(x)$ in $\Bbb R^\omega$ with the box topology there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $f(y)\in U$ whenever $|x-y|<\epsilon$.

Comment: I’ve expanded some of these comments and added a bit more to make a tentative answer. I’ve indicated what you need to do in order to work the problem, but I’ve not said anything about the mathematical details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Bbb R^\omega$ is the set of infinite sequences of real numbers; $f,g$, and $h$ are functions from $\Bbb R$ to this set of sequences. Take $f$, for instance: it sends the real number $\pi$ to the sequence $\langle \pi,2\pi,3\pi,\ldots\rangle$, meaning that $f(\pi)=\langle \pi,2\pi,3\pi,\ldots\rangle$. Similarly, $f(1)$ is the sequence $\langle 1,2,3,\ldots\rangle$ of positive integers, $f(-1)$ is the sequence $\langle -1,-2,-3,\ldots\rangle$, $f(0)=\langle 0,0,0,\ldots\rangle$, and

$$\begin{align*}
f\left(\frac16\right)&=\left\langle\frac16,\frac26,\frac36,\frac46,\frac56,\frac66,\frac76,\frac86,\ldots\right\rangle\\
&=\left\langle\frac16,\frac13,\frac12,\frac23,\frac56,1,\frac76,\frac43,\ldots\right\rangle\;.
\end{align*}$$

The function $g$ is even simpler: it just sends each real number to the constant sequence at that real number, so that $g(1)=\langle 1,1,1,\ldots\rangle$, $g(\pi)=\langle\pi,\pi,\pi,\ldots\rangle$, and so on.

As a final example, $h(\pi)$ is the sequence $$h(\pi)=\left\langle\pi,\frac{\pi}2,\frac{\pi}3,\frac{\pi}4,\ldots\right\rangle\;.$$

Three important topologies on this set of sequences are the uniform topology $\tau_u$, the product topology $\tau_p$, and the box topology $\tau_b$. Each of them makes $\Bbb R^\omega$ a topological space, and we can ask whether $f,g$, or $h$ is continuous when we give $\Bbb R^\omega$ one of these topologies and the domain $\Bbb R$ its usual topology. In order to answer the question, you’re going to have to have some understanding of the three topologies; knowing a base for each of them is sufficient. Suppose that $\mathscr{B}_u$ is a base for $\tau_u$, $\mathscr{B}_p$ is a base for $\tau_p$, and $\mathscr{B}_b$ is a base for $\tau_b$. To show, for instance, that $h$ is continuous with respect to $\tau_u$, you must show that

> for any $x\in\Bbb R$ and any $B\in\mathscr{B}_u$ such that $h(x)\in B$, there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $h(y)\in B$ whenever $|x-y|<\epsilon$,

thereby showing that $h$ is continuous at each $x\in X$.

To show that $h$ is not continuous with respect to $\tau_u$, you must

> find an $x\in\Bbb R$ and a $B\in\mathscr{B}_u$ such that $h(x)\in B$, but for each $\epsilon>0$ there is a $y_\epsilon\in\Bbb R$ such that $|x-y|<\epsilon$ and $h(y)\notin B$:

this shows that $h$ is not continuous at $x$.

Your first step should be to identify bases $\mathscr{B}_u$, $\mathscr{B}_p$, and $\mathscr{B}_b$.

The ordinary product topology $\tau_p$ is normally described in terms of a particular basis; its elements are sets of the form $\prod_{k\in\Bbb Z^+}U_k$, where each $U_k$ is open in $\Bbb R$, and $U_k=\Bbb R$ for all but finitely many indices $k$.

The box topology is normally described in terms of a similar base: its elements are **all** products of the form $\prod_{k\in\Bbb Z^+}U_k$, where each $U_k$ is open in $\Bbb R$.

Finally, $\tau_u$ is usually described in terms of a nbhd base at each point. (Remember that a point in this space is actually an infinite sequence of real numbers.) For $x=\langle x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots\rangle\in\Bbb R^\omega$ and $r>0$ let

$$N(x,r)=\{\langle y_1,y_2,y_3,\ldots\rangle\in\Bbb R^\omega:|x_k-y_k|<r\text{ for all }k\in\Bbb Z^+\}\;,$$

and let

$$B(x,r)=\bigcup_{0<s<r}N(x,s)\;;$$

then $\mathscr{B}_u=\left\{B(x,r):x\in\Bbb R^\omega\text{ and }r>0\right\}$ is a base for the uniform topology $\tau_u$ on $\Bbb R^\omega$.

If you’ve been given a slightly different definition of any of these topologies, you should try to see why it’s equivalent to what I’ve given here.

There isn’t any really good way to draw pictures of the maps $f,g$, and $h$.

Comment: I guess the $B(x,r)$ are not base sets for $\mathcal B_u$, see Marek's answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/626334/proof-that-gt-t-t-t-is-not-continuous-with-uniform-topology#626450

Comment: @Stefan: As I had them defined, for fixed $x$ they form a local nbhd base at $x$, but not an open nbhd base. However, I’ve fixed it so that they are now open. (Your comment came during the not-quite-a-year during which I was not reading MSE.)