# "Proof" that $g(t) = (t,t,t,...)$ is not continuous with uniform topology

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

Let $g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^{\omega}$ be the function
$$
 g(t) := (t, t, t, \ldots).
$$
If $\mathbb R^{\omega}$ is equipped with the uniform topology, and $\mathbb R$ with the standard topology, then is $g$ continuous? According to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/297303/what-about-the-continuity-of-these-functions-in-the-uniform-topology)
 it is. I have a different proof which yields another conclusion, but I cannot see whats wrong with the proof?

Let $Y = \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} Y_i \subseteq R^{\omega}$, then
$$
 g^{-1}(Y) = \bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty} Y_i.
$$
**Proof:** Let $x \in g^{-1}(Y)$, then $g(x) = (x,x,x,\ldots) \in Y$ and so $x \in Y_i$ for all $i$, thus $x \in \bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty} Y_i$. Conversely let $x \in \bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty} Y_i$, then $g(x) = (x,x,x,\ldots) \in \prod Y_i = Y$, and so $x \in g^{-1}(Y)$. $\square$

A basis set $B(x,r)$ in the uniform topoloy on $\mathbb R^{\omega}$ has the form
$$
 B(x,r) = \{ y = (y_i) : |x_i - y_i| < r \mbox{ for all }i \}
        = \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} B(x_i, r) = \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} (x_i - r, x_i + r)
$$
so in particular for $x = (1,1/2,1/3,\ldots)$ the set
$$
 B(x, 1) = \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{n} - 1, \frac{1}{n} + 1 \right)
$$
is open in the uniform topology. But
$$
 g^{-1}(B(x,1)) = \bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{n} - 1, \frac{1}{n} + 1 \right) = (0,1]
$$
is not open, so $g$ is not continuous? What goes wrong here....

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'uniform topology' but you are trying to use finite-dimension intuition about product topology to inifnite-dimension. Your set $B(x,1)$ is not a ball and even not an open set hence yours 'contradiction'. Please read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology#Definition

Comment: I am not using the product topology, but the uniform topology, which is a refinement of the product topology and defined as the metric topology induced by $\rho(x,y) = \sup\{ d'(x_i, y_i) : i \in \mathbb N \}$ on $\mathbb R^{\omega}$, where $d'(x_i,y_i) := \min\{1,d(x_i,y_i)\}$ and $d$ denotes the usual euclidean metric on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: I see, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I think $g(t)$ is continuous with uniform topology on $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$? A basis element around an image point is $\prod (t-\epsilon, t+\epsilon)$ and its pre-image is $(t-\epsilon, t+\epsilon)$ which is open in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$B(x,r)$ is not open in uniform topology. For example take $y = (1, 1/2, 1/3, \dots)$. Then $z := (1, 1, 1, \dots) \in B(y, 1)$ but clearly $B(z, \epsilon) \not \subset B(y, 1)$ for every $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: @Daniel: are you saying that uniform topology is finer than the box topology? And also that $g$ is not continuous?

Comment: No, the uniform topology is coarser than the box-topology. In the box-topology, the radius of the balls can have $\liminf = 0$, not in the uniform topology. But the uniform topology is (strictly) finer than the product topology. I'm befuddled. On the one hand, $g$ is isometric per Brian's answer, on the other, I don't see a flaw in the OP's argument.

Comment: Ah, dang. It __is__ a neighbourhood in the uniform topology, but _not open_. I see it now.

Comment: @Daniel: ah, I see what you mean by the radius, fine. Still, consider the OP's $B(x, 1)$ with $x = (1, 1/2, \dots)$. $(1, 1, \dots) \in B(x, 1)$ but there is no open subset of $B(x, 1)$ containing it.

Comment: Right, I saw that too. Explain that in your answer, and you have an upvote.

Comment: @Daniel: done. And thanks for the discussion. I stared at this question for quite some time until I realized where the problem is; ..it's so natural to take openness for granted :)

Comment: Also done. Yes, it is a neighbourhood, and it "looks" open, so it's easy to fall for it.

Comment: thx. but two questions left. 1) are you sure that the $B(x,r)$ are a basis for the box topology, because they enforce that all radii are the same, and in the usual base of the box topology all radii could be different, I don't see how to achieve this with unions of $B(x,r)$ sets. ii) $B(z,\varepsilon) \not \subset B(y,1)$ for every $\varepsilon > 0$. Why does this shows that the $B(x,r)$ are not open, maybe there could be some other open set $U_z$ not of the form $B(z,\varepsilon)$ contained in $B(y,1)$, why is this excluded?

Comment: @Stefan: 1) you are correct, it seems your $B(x,r)$ generate a topology that lies strictly between uniform and box topology. I'll remove the note. 2) any open set containing $z$ must also contain $B(z, \epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon$ (that's the definition of basis).

Comment: @Stefan The notation $B(x,r)$ is misleading, since $$\prod_{k=1}^\infty B(x_k,r)$$ contains sequences with $\sup d'(x_k,y_k) = r$. So the product of open balls (with the same radius) with centre $x_k$ is a neighbourhood of $x = (x_k)$, but not an open ball in the uniform metric. It is, in fact, not an open set.

Comment: 2) yes, by definition of the open balls. thx!